# Clash Royale Shop Card : New update over Old?

Tags: clash-royale

How is the gold for the cards in the shop calculated:

The new update makes it more obvious but the old update?

Which update has a better deal?

New Common:2,4,6,8,10,12 ect
Old Common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [old card scaling](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sjBi7vvCjKUx2BTxEhDYSNAucMW99xIyCdQpHcS1mBE/pubhtml) and made litle graph for you.
The new scaling is done by formula y=2x for commons ([found on wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Shop)).
So I made this graph.
[image]

Here you can see that new scaling is much cost eficient than the old where cost of next card would rise exponentialy and now it is more linear scaling. In the end the card costs are now much cheaper than used to be.